# Pagination, display 'Next 20 Results' etc

Tags: entries, pagination

Just a quicky regarding pagination. 
I have a paginated results list with a limit of 20 results in a page.

I'm wondering how I owuld go about making a pagination that shows the number of results on the next page.

i.e. 
If I have 105 results, the pagination link says 'next 20 results', up to the fifth page, which would then say 'next 5 results'.

Not sure if there is an easier way to do it other than a load of maths to work it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about a load of math, but if you've got `pageInfo` setup like in the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate), should be something like this:

```
{% set totalPages = pageInfo.totalPages %}
{% set itemsPerPage = 20 %}
{% set currentPage = pageInfo.currentPage %}
{% set totalItems = pageInfo.total %}

{% set wholeItems = (totalPages - 1) * itemsPerPage %}
{% set remainderItems = totalItems - wholeItems %}

{% if currentPage == totalPages - 1 %}
    Next {{ remainderItems }} items.
{% else %}
    Next {{ itemsPerPage }} items.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant by maths!  juts wondered if there was an easier way, but I'll roll with your suggestion! Thanks!